# Moto does not appear to be mocking aws interactions in a pytest

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pytest, boto3, moto

Say I want to mock the following:

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
resource = session.resource('iam')
iam_users = resource.users.all()
policies = resource.policies.filter(Scope='AWS', OnlyAttached=True, PolicyUsageFilter='PermissionsPolicy')
```

How do I go about starting to mock this with in pytest? I could create mocked objects by creating a dummy class and the necessary attributes, but I suspect that's the wrong approach.

Some additional details, here's what I'm trying to test out:

```
def test_check_aws_profile(self, mocker):
    mocked_boto3 = mocker.patch('myapp.services.utils.boto3.Session')
    mocker.patch(mocked_boto3.client.get_caller_identity.get, return_value='foo-account-id')
    assert 'foo-account-id' == my_func('foo')

#in myapp.services.utils.py
def my_func(profile):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name=profile)
    client = session.client('sts')
    aws_account_number = client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
    return aws_account_number
```

But I can't quite seem to be able to get this patched correctly. I'm trying to make it so that I can patch session and the function calls in that method

I tried using moto and got this:

```
@mock_sts
def test_check_aws_profile(self):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='foo')
    client = session.client('sts')
    client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
```

But I'm running into

```
>           raise ProfileNotFound(profile=profile_name)
E           botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (foo) could not be found
```

So it seems like it's not mocking anything :|

Edit:

Turns out you need to have the mocked credentials in a config and credentials file for this to work.

Comment: *"How do I go about starting...?"* is too broad a question for SO, but maybe have a look at e.g. http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you want, so I'll give you something to start.

You let `unittest.mock` to mock everything for you, for example. (Useful reading: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

`module.py`:

```
import boto3

def function():
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name="foobar")
    client = session.resource("sts")
    return client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
```

`test_module.py`:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

import module

@patch("module.boto3")  # this creates mock which is passed to test below
def test_function(mocked_boto):
    # mocks below are magically created by unittest.mock when they are accessed
    mocked_session = mocked_boto.Session()
    mocked_client = mocked_session.resource()
    mocked_identity = mocked_client.get_caller_identity()

    # now mock the return value of .get()
    mocked_identity.get.return_value = "foo-bar-baz"

    result = module.function()
    assert result == "foo-bar-baz"

    # we can make sure mocks were called properly, for example
    mocked_identity.get.assert_called_once_with("Account")
```

Results of pytest run:

```
$ pytest
================================ test session starts ================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.7.6, pytest-5.3.2, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /private/tmp/one
collected 1 item                                                                    

test_module.py .                                                              [100%]

================================= 1 passed in 0.09s =================================
```

I would also recommend to install `pytest-socket` and run `pytest --disable-socket` to make sure your tests do not talk with network by accident.

Comment: Ah, this might work, I tried something similar but can't quite get it working correctly. I've updated my question with the sample code I'm using.

Comment: @Stupid.Fat.Cat I've updated the code in the answer to match your updated question.

Comment: Downvoted due to reinventing the wheel.  This is entirely the wrong approach. Testing of any code which interacts with AWS via boto3 should use the [`botocore.stub`](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/stubber.html) class for stubbing the transport at the appropriate boundary, and/or a higher level AWS mock such as [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto).

Comment: That's exactly why I said in the beginning "I'm not sure what exactly you want". If the idea is just to exclude all boto3 stuff from code under test -- why not to mock it away? If the idea is to test *interactions* with AWS, that's a different story.

Comment: If you are not sure what O.P. wants, then ask clarifying questions in the comments and/or vote-to-close the question as unclear. This answer is really sending them off in the wrong direction (for example, `boto3.Session` does autodiscovery of credentials which you do not want to happen in test - and it will be a lot of extra unnecessary work to correctly prevent that by using `unittest.mock` only).

Comment: As for "why not to mock it [the boto3 module] away", it's a reasonable question: if you do this, you miss any changes in boto3 itself. The best place to mock is at the boundary of network access.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `moto`, you can use the `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` environment variable, to point it to a dummy credentials file which can be kept in the tests folder.
You can define your profiles there. Example:

Files: `test_stuff.py.    dummy_aws_credentials`

***test_stuff.py:***

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import boto3
import pytest
from moto import mock_sts


@pytest.fixture(scope='module')
def aws_credentials():
    """Mocked AWS Credentials for moto."""
    moto_credentials_file_path = Path(__file__).parent.absolute() / 'dummy_aws_credentials'
    os.environ['AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE'] = str(moto_credentials_file_path)


@mock_sts
def test_check_aws_profile(aws_credentials):
    session = boto3.Session(profile_name='foo')
    client = session.client('sts')
    client.get_caller_identity().get('Account')
```

***dummy_aws_credentials:***

```
[foo]
aws_access_key_id = mock
aws_secret_access_key = mock
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there is nothing wrong with manually patching boto using `mock.patch`, you could also consider using a higher level testing utility like [moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto).

Comment: I've updated the question with moto with some issues